# c# Sorting a list by a property of a type

Tags: c#

I have this type:

```
public class PackagesType
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public string price { get; set; }
    public string subtitle { get; set; }
    public string colorOfBox { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
}
```

And I am trying to sort elements on a list with this type by "order".

I tried:

```
    PackagesList.OrderBy(p => p.order);
```

But the result is a random list. this order line does not affect the list at all.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `OrderBy` is non-mutational i.e. it returns a new ordered instance.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay After being materialized, of course

Comment: Got it., thank you :)

Comment: `PackagesList.Sort((x, y) => x.order.CompareTo(y.order));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To sort a `List<T>` *inplace*, use `Sort`:

```
  PackagesList.Sort((left, right) => left.order.CompareTo(right.order));
```

Please note, that `OrderBy` keeps `PackagesList` intact, while returning sorted sequence